# How to set positions of form in html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set positions of forms. My teacher says this can be achieved using `<Frameset>` tag but this tag creates borders between the two frames and I don't want those borders. I have basically have 2 forms , one contains basic text and the other one contains some images. I want both these forms to display side by side not one below the other. Is there any way to achieve this?? please help.

Comment: You could use `float`s and `display:inline`'s to get things side by side also? Or look at different CSS frameworks like Foundation or Bootstrap that use columns.

Comment: your teacher tells you to use frameset? Are you studying history? Also Forms may contain images and other elements, but basically they are good for input elements.

Comment: This basically boils down to "Go an learn CSS", there are lots of ways to lay out things so they are next to each other and different ones are useful in different circumstances.

Comment: You should tell your teacher that we have now entered the 21st century, the second decade even, and people don't use framesets any more. Or, find a new university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

http://fiddle.jshell.net/FBXZC/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="halfwidth">
        I am One Half
    </div>
    <div class="halfwidth">
        <img src="http://www.metal4.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/steel-panther.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.halfwidth {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

PS: get yourself a new teacher or go complain about him, he obv. has no idea of anything.

Comment: No problem, and by the way, the word you were looking for was element, not forms. In HTML  there are elements ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to style forms.

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aa6zJ/) for the sake of demo.

```
form
{
 background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO and I'm glad to see a new student in web development. I don't want to go against your teacher, for he/she is probably teaching you the behaviors of frameset, but frameset is not the best way.

This is what you should do :

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="left-side"></div>
     <div class="right-side"></div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G5HY8/)

Comment: This is putting the frames or divisions on left and right side but it still puts them one after the other.

Comment: are they not "side-by-side"?

Comment: Actually the content takes more space then half of the screen. So it displays the content in half width only but is still putting the divisions one below the other.

Comment: that's because you have to adjust the width to any width you wan to use. As you learn more, you will start using widths in percentages because of responsiveness. Fixed widths (px) are a thing of the past. You wan to use percentages now(%)

Comment: I used float left and right as a trick to create a separation between both setions witout having to create a separate <div> for it or a margin-left that can be buggy sometimes specially in older IE versions. But there are so many ways to do this. This is only one way to do it.

Comment: I tried setting the width but still same results. I used `display:block` and it is working after that.

Comment: huh!!! display:block is supposed to stack them on top of each other. Totally the opposite to what you asked

Comment: But it is working fine.

Comment: ok, well, that's the important thing. My guess is another element is causing this somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use Dreamweaver to give you the exact position for each element. In general  tags define the positions.